# increase figure size when using square=True in sns.heatmap(...)

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, heatmap

Why is it that my figure size is not expanding in width when I use sns. An example of the code is:

```
plt.figure(figsize=(10, 6))
g= sns.heatmap(df,yticklabels=50,xticklabels=4,vmin=0.0,vmax=1.0,cmap='gnuplot',cbar_kws={"ticks":[0.0,0.5,1.0]},
              mask=mdf,square=True)
```

[see example plot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UXqL1.png)
it doesnt expand in width, only in height, no matter how i change to values higher than 10

Comment: The figure itself expands of course. But then you plot something with equal aspect ratio. In your case the axes is much larger in height direction, so it is contrained to 6 inches in height, no matter what width you specify. To get a larger plot, you would need to make the figure larger in height. E.g. `figsize=(5,10)`

Comment: it just gets taller and stays mushed in.

Comment: Yes, if by "mushed in" you mean it keeps equal aspect, as specified by `square=True`, that is of course the intended behaviour.